# New Task button is not visible in Lightning Task related list

Tags: lightning, tasks, related-list

New Task button is not visible in lightning, but I can see it in classic.

Main Task - Custom Object
Sub Task related list - Task Object

I followed below steps. But didn't resolve the issue.

1. Ticked new task button from page layout-> related list ->wrench icon
2. Lightning app builder -> related list - enhanced list, show list view action bar - ticked

[image: Task related list in lightning]